# passing a class variable to API function

Tags: api, c++11, pointers, pass-by-reference

I want to track a global variable that I am passing into an API function. I found that one could do it using a class:

```
template <class T>
class MonitoredVariable
{
public:
    MonitoredVariable() {}
    MonitoredVariable(const T& value) : m_value(value) {}

    //T operator T() const { return m_value; }

    const MonitoredVariable& operator = (const T& value)
    {
        PlugIn::gResultOut << "value changed " << std::endl;
        m_value = value;
        return *this;
    }


private:
    T m_value;
};
```

The API function takes variables as

```
bool APIFunction(double time, bool *is_done, double *fraction_done);
```

The following gives me an error:

```
ImagePtr Im;
bool is_done;
MonitoredVariable<double*> fraction_done;
bool frameready = Im->APIFunction(2.1, is_done, fraction_done);

ERROR:
    error C2664: cannot convert argument 3 from 'MonitoredVariable<double *>' to 'double *'
```

what would I have to change here?
thx!

Comment: Is use of `*is_done` in the function call a typo? If not, you should really learn the basics of the language from a [good textbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: yes its a typo. fraction_done is the issue here....

Comment: Please fix that in your post so others won't be distracted/confused by it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this is what you want:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class MonitoredVariable
{
public:
    MonitoredVariable() {}
    MonitoredVariable(const T& value) : m_value(value) {}

    //T operator T() const { return m_value; }

    const MonitoredVariable& operator = (const T& value)
    {
        //PlugIn::gResultOut << "value changed " << std::endl;
        m_value = value.m_value;
        return *this;
    }

    void printValue() {
        std::cout << m_value;
    }

    T& getValue() {
        return m_value;
    }

private:
    T m_value;
};

bool func(double firstDouble, bool *is_done, double* fraction_done) {
    // do stuff

    *fraction_done = firstDouble + (40.23 * 5);
    *is_done = true;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    bool is_done = true;
    MonitoredVariable<double> fraction_done;

    func(2.10, &is_done, &fraction_done.getValue());

    fraction_done.printValue();

    return 0;
}
```

So basically we have a Class called MonitoredVariable which has a variable called m_value. I'm not really sure why you wanted it to be a pointer, because we can also take the address of a normal double variable.

Answer (score 0):

In the following it makes perhaps more sense what I want to achieve. I want to input a class variable into an API function and monitor the variable in real time. This value goes from zero to 1 every 3 ms or so. Yet I try to avoid using while loop and track it within the class with overloaded = operator.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class MonitoredVariable
{
public:
    MonitoredVariable() {}
    MonitoredVariable(const T& value) : m_value(value) {}


    void printValue() {
        std::cout << m_value;
    }

    const MonitoredVariable& operator = (const T& value)
    {
        m_value = value.m_value;
        if(m_value> 0.8) std::cout << m_value;  // *THIS NEVER GETS PRINTED!!!*

        return *this;
    }


    T& getValue() {

        return m_value;
    }

private:
    T m_value;
};

bool func(bool *is_done, double* fraction_done) {

    unsigned long c = 1;

    while (*is_done)
    {
        *fraction_done =  (double) 0.01*c;
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));
        c++;
        if (*fraction_done >= 1) *is_done = false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{

    bool is_done = true; 
    MonitoredVariable<double> *MonitoredVariablePtr = new MonitoredVariable<double>();

    std::future<bool> fu = std::async(std::launch::async,func, &is_done, &MonitoredVariablePtr->getValue()); 


    // IF I UNCOMMENT THIS, IT PRINTS...
     /*
    while(is_done)
    {
    if(MonitoredVariablePtr->getValue() > 0.8)  MonitoredVariablePtr->printValue();
    }
    */

return 0;
}
```

Why does not the (if(m_value> 0.8) std::cout << m_value) line within the class never gets printed when the value is updated?

THX!